# Nuxt return sitemap.xml route with async data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, xml-sitemap

Is there a way to get async data for XML from API and then display it as `website.com/sitemap.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot... but take a look to the [nuxt sitemap module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/)

you can use the `routes` option to load async data (see eg. https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options#from-a-function-which-returns-a-promise)